# iPhone - having a superclass calling methods on subclasses...(?)

Tags: iphone

I have several subclasses that derive from one superclass. Lets call this superclass "classA".

All subclasses of classA have a method called **doStuff:(id)sender** and every of these methods in each class does things relative to that class.

The problem is that I have to call doStuff from classA.

How do I do that?

Should I declare **doStuff:(id)sender** on classA as an empty method, like

```
- (void) doStuff:(id)sender {
}
```

just to have it compile correctly and then overwrite that on the subclass declaring it again? Is this the correct way to do that?

thanks.

Answer (score 3):

That is a good way for that case, just have the superclass implement a default method that does nothing.  Or it can also throw an exception so you don't forget to provide an implementation, but usually it's good enough to document in the header that subclasses need to provide an implementation.

Comment: Another alternative would be to have the code in ClassA use introspection to send the message, for example `[self performSelector:@selector(doStuff:) withObject:nil]`. That would also cause an exception to be thrown if the subclass didn't provide an implementation. I'd probably stick with Kendall's suggestion though most of the time -- just create an empty method in the superclass.

Comment: I think if the intent is that every subclass have it, it's better to advertise the presence of it...  although if it's meant to be a private method, I could go either way.  performSelector:withObject: is slower than a straight call though.  I almost mentioned using a protocol as an option but that just seems wrong to have to mark every subclass when they are inheriting anyway.

Comment: thanks guys. I have implemented using Kendall suggestion and it is working fine!